# Ошибка синтаксиса MariaDB в phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

При переносе сайта на Wordpress на локальный сервер, для замены url использовал ниже приведенный запрос через phpmyadmin. И раньше проблем никогда не возникало:

```
UPDATE
  wp_options
SET
  option_value = REPLACE(
    option_value,
    'http://example.com',
    'http://localhost/example.com'
  )
WHERE
  option_name = 'home' OR
  option_name = 'siteurl'
```

А сейчас в окне запроса, `REPLACE`, подчеркивается со следующей ошибкой:

> A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the
>   previous one. (около REPLACE)

А при самом запросе вываливается следующая ошибка:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 1

Перепробовал разные способы что нашел, но ничего так и не помогло. На локалке использую xampp 5.6.14-3.

Comment: при переносе wp можно использовать [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/), если будут проблемы - можно баг им запостить, пусть думают ))

Comment: и вы прямо этот запрос пытаетесь выполнить? Может вы в изначальном запросе опечатались (например, лишнюю кавычку в адресе поставили), а здесь в примере этой ошибки нет. Если запрос один-в-один, попробуйте в консоли (не через pma) выполнить запрос, может сам pma что-нибудь не так делает?

Comment: @BOPOH да, запрос один в один. Через консоль запрос нормально отработал. Наверное проблема все-таки в pmа. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: такая же ошибка что-то связанное с версией phpmyadmin'a, решение тоже так и не нашел.